# How can I store values in a dictionary with a while loop and show them as a table in python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So the code I'm doing right now as to create a catalogue, so first it asks the user how many items he wants to add to the catalogue and the to introduce 7 attributes to this item, being name, type, color, power, light type, price and units. In addition to this I'm also storing the id (first item would be 1, second is 2, etc) and the price + taxes.

lee_entero is a function that makes sures the number introduced is positive and an integer.

To do this i do the following:

```
prod={}

l=[]

n= lee_entero("how many items? ")
        
        for i in range(1,n+1):
        
            p_nombre = input("Name: ")
            p_tipo = input("Type: ")
            p_color = lee_color("Color: ")
            p_potencia = lee_RealPositivo("Power(K): ")
            p_tipoLuz = lee_luz("Light type (amarillo, azul o blanco): ")
            p_precio = lee_RealPositivo("Price without taxes: ")
            if (p_precio <= 50):
             print("Low price ")
            elif (p_precio <= 100):
             print("Medium Price ")
            else:
             print("High price ")
            p_total = p_precio + p_precio*IVA/100
            p_unidades = lee_entero("Units: ")
            ids=i
           
            prod={"Product nº":ids, "name": p_nombre, "type": p_tipo, "color": p_color, "power": p_potencia, "light type": p_tipoLuz, "price": p_precio, "total": p_total, "units": p_unidades  }
            l.append(prod)
            i=i+1
```

And then I want this to be displayed as a table for which i have tried:

```
print("{:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15}".format("id", "Nombre", "Tipo", "Color", "Potencia", "Tipo Luz", "Precio", "Precio IVA", "Unidades"))
           print("*******************************************************************************************************************************************************")

   for key, value in prod.items():

       elid, nombre, tipo, color, potencia, tipoluz, precio, precioiva, unidades = value

       print("{:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15}".format(elid, nombre, tipo, color, potencia, tipoluz, precio, precioiva, unidades))
```

but this doesn't work.

Overall im looking for a way to store the values of each product and then display them as a table without importing any libraries, but right now is giving me the TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object and I haven't been able to make it work, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a dict, so using

```
for key, value in prod.items():
```

will generate pair

```
key == "Product nº"
value == ids
```

in the first iteration. So you are trying to unpack value, which is int. To achieve what you want, to can do something like:

```
for value in prod.values():
    print("{:<15}".format(value),end=" ")
print()
```

which will print all values from the dictionary without a new line, and then add a new line at the end